# how to enable or disable the book in/book out button in ajax table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am learning ajax, please help me to solve this : how to enable or disable the book in/book out button in ajax table based on the book in or book out field result.

my index.php
    --------------------
    
    
    
        Book in-out

```
</head>


<body>
<div id="container" class="text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to Book in-out</h1>
    <div id="searchbox" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search your Service No">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="result"></div>



</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function(){

    $('#search').keyup (function(){

        var search = $('#search').val();

        $.ajax({

            url:'db.php',
            data:{search:search},
            type:'POST',
            success:function (data){

                if(!data.error){
                    $('#result').html(data)
                    $("#bookin,#bookout").attr("disabled",true);
                }
                if (!empty ($time_out)){

                    $("#bookout").attr("disabled",false);   
                }
            }

        });



    })


});

</script>

</body>
</html>
---------------
my db.php
-------------
<?php 
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bookin_out');
$search=$_POST['search'];
if(!empty($search)){

    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_bookin_out WHERE service_no LIKE '$search%' ";
    $search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$search_query){
        die('Query failed'.mysqli_error());
    }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)){
        $service_no=$row ['service_no'];
        $rank=$row ['rank'];
        $name=$row ['name'];
        $trade=$row ['trade'];
        $unit=$row ['unit'];
        $section=$row ['section'];
        $contact_no=$row ['contact_no'];
        $mess=$row ['mess'];
        $billet=$row ['billet'];
        $date_out=$row ['date_out'];
        $time_out=$row ['time_out'];
        $date_in=$row ['date_in'];
        $time_in=$row ['time_in'];
        $remarks=$row ['remarks'];
        }


    ?>

<table border="1" align="center" class="table table-striped text-capitalize">
  <tr align="center" valign="middle" class="alert-info">
    <td><strong>Service No</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Rank</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>    
    <td><strong>Trade</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Unit</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Section</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Contact No</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Mess</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Billet</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date Out</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Time Out</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date in</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Time in</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Book Out</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Book in</strong></td>  

  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
<tr align="center" valign="middle" class="text-capitalize">

      <td><?php echo $service_no; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rank; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $name; ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $trade; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $unit; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $section; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $contact_no; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $mess; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $billet; ?></td>   
      <td><?php echo $date_out; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $time_out; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $date_in; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $time_in; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $remarks; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "<input type='submit' name='bookout' id='bookout' value='Book Out'>"; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "<input type='submit' name='bookin' id='bookin' value='Book In'>"; ?></td>
    </tr>  
    <?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)); } ?> 
  </table>
```

Comment: You cannot repeat the id as you are doing for `bookin` and `bookout` - the ID MUST be unique! Also, if the buttons are `submit` you should ensure, in your javascript, that you prevent the default action from occurring - otherwise the form will submit in the usual manner ( assuming there is a form ) or change the submit to standard button

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what you are asking, your question is pretty vague.

but first of, if you have multiple #bookin and #bookout, this will fail. use classes, as ids are unique. jquery wont have it any other way =)
I can't see where you would get data.error from so ive removed it and replaced with success and error functions.

```
       $.ajax({
            url:'db.php',
            data:{search:search},
            type:'POST',
            success:function (data){
                    $('#result').html(data)
                    //Use prop if your jquery is 1.6+
                    $(".bookin,.bookout").prop("disabled",true);
            },
            error: function(data){
             //handle errors here
            }
        });
```

Depending on what defines a bookin or bookout as disabled, i'd do this in php.